# Bash and minus floating points

Tags: bash

I have code like this in Bash :

```
read a
read b
c=96.0
d=100.0
echo "scale=2;($b*$c - $a*$d)/$a" |bc
```

And it prints result of this expression :

> (b*96-a*100)/a

But when result is between -1 and 0 
it gives something like this : -.99

For smaller values it prints result correctly.
So, my question is, how to force program to put 0 when printing

> 0.123123(...)

? Not only

> .123123(...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use printf:

```
$ printf "%0.2f" "$(echo 'scale=2; 1.9/10.0' | bc)"
0.19
```

printf is (also) a bash builtin

Comment: May not work for some locales, try `LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8 printf "%0.2f" .19`

Comment: @eugene: works for me (prints `0.19`); what's the problem with it?

Comment: The problem is that the decimal separator is a comma in the RU locale (as it is in the NL locale). However, this works for me:  export LC_ALL=nl_NL && printf "%0.2f\n" 0,18. This does not work: export LC_ALL=nl_NL && printf "%0.2f\n" 0.18 - it generates the error message "-bash: printf: 0.18: invalid number".

Comment: @micans: that means that eugene is simply using wrong input (`.19` instead of `,19`); possibly, `bc` doesn't honour the locale number format as well. I can't really fix that. Of course my numbers are just a sample and I assumed en_US or C locale